# Sonata Media Bundle and Translation

Tags: symfony, translation, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have a web portal built with Symfony 2.8 and Sonata Admin.

I am using Sonata Translation along with Gedmo's Translatable behavior to manage multilanguage entities in my website and it's working fine.

I added Sonata Media to handle images and files but I can't translate them. When I try to add `@Gedmo\Translatable` to a Media entity I get this error:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media|null
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="video_1", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 */
protected $video1;
```

Console error:

```
[Gedmo\Exception\InvalidMappingException]                                    
Unable to find translatable [video1] as mapped property in entity - AppBundle\Entity\Module
```

Is it possible to translate uploaded files or do I have to manually handle it without Sonata Media?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to translate field, that do not exist it database. This property contains collection of Media entities.
Try append

> @Gedmo\Translatable

to field in

> \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media